# APNs Provider API HTTP/2 using c++, openssl

Tags: c++

I try to send header frame and data frame with HPACK, and I received goaway frame with COMPRESSION_ERROR (0x9) from APNS.

my step:

1. send setting frame
2. recv setting frame
3. send ACK
4. recv ACK
5. send header frame
6. send data frame

requset:

```
HEADERS
  - END_STREAM
  + END_HEADERS
  :method = POST
  :scheme = https
  :path = /3/device/ad92823c9e42e37241b6cdf6f583c6cdf5dcc21289c57fb6641213abeff8095d
  host = api.development.push.apple.com
DATA
  + END_STREAM
  { "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
```

Hex:

```
00 00 77 01 04 00 00 00 01     HEADER FRAME
83                             :method = POST
86                             :scheme = https
04                             :path =   (Literal Header Field without Indexing)
4a                             length(74)
2f 33 2f 64 65 76 69 63        /3/device/ad92823c9e42e37241b6cdf6f583c6cdf5dcc21289c57fb6641213abeff8095d
65 2f 61 64 39 32 38 32 
33 63 39 65 34 32 65 33 
37 32 34 31 62 36 63 64 
66 36 66 35 38 33 63 36 
63 64 66 35 64 63 63 32 
31 32 38 39 63 35 37 66 
62 36 36 34 31 32 31 33 
61 62 65 66 66 38 30 39 
35 64 
66                              host =  
1e                              length(30)
61 70 69 2e 64 65 76 65         api.development.psuh.apple.com 
6c 6f 70 6d 65 6e 74 2e
70 75 73 68 2e 61 70 70
6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d

00 00 21 00 01 00 00 00 01      DATA FRAME
7b 20 22 61 70 73 22 20         { "aps" : { "alert" : "hello" } }
3a 20 7b 20 22 61 6c 65 
72 74 22 20 3a 20 22 68 
65 6c 6c 6f 22 20 7d 20 
7d
```

any tips?
thanks